# Separate a string value in two integers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

My problem is the following.
I have a huge dataset of forest stands. 
All the information are separated but in many cases the stands have different age and this is marked in one attribute
for example

```
age = 14/2
```

This marks that one part of the stand is 140 years old and the rest 20 years.

My problem is that I need to have these two values separate, optimally in two colums:

```
age 1 = 14
age 2 = 2
```

Also, not always is the first number consisted of two digits, and vice versa.

Any ideas how I can do it?
I was thinking of using FieldPyCalculator, but I'm not any good with Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to split this string into two integers you can use the Python  [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) function and convert the resulting two list entrys from type string to type integer.

```
age = '14/2'
ages = age.split("/")
age 1 = int(ages[0])
age 2 = int(ages[1])
```

or as a function:

```
def split_age(self, age):
    return(int(age.split("/")[0]), int(age.split("/")[1]))
```

This function would return a touple of age integers.

Comment: Martin, than you very much, this works very well.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by @Martin! Alternatively, you can also achieve this via the normal **Field Calculator** by using the following commands:

When creating the column `age 1`:

```
regexp_replace("Age" , '/[0-9]*', '')
```

When creating the column `age 2`:

```
regexp_replace("Age" , '[0-9]*/', '')
```

---

Note: Make sure to place the forward slash `/` at the beginning if you want to exclude all terms after it; place `/` at the end to exclude all terms before it.

Comment: I don't know if this is working in the field calculator but with regex you can use [0-9]* to look for n numbers until a char.

Comment: @Martin, brilliant! Yup, it works like a charm. Thank you for that, I learnt something :)

Answer (score 1):

One more option using the Field Calculator,

For age1,

```
left("Age", length("Age") -  strpos("Age" ,'/'))
```

For age2,

```
right("Age", length("Age") - strpos("Age" ,'/')-1)
```

Comment: Another very good method, I never used the `left` and `right` operations before but great to see how it applies here!